# Can I replicate only certain repositories to a GitHub replication node?

Tags: github, github-enterprise

I am looking to setup a two GitHub Enterprise replication nodes, let's say Replica_Node1 and Replica_Node2. There is 1 master node with two repositories 1 and 2 on it. I am looking for a way to only replicate repository 1 to Replica_Node1 and repository 2 to Replica_Node 2. I am not able to find any use cases like this. Would anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Git doesn't have "organizations". It only has repositories.

Comment: To add a bit to @phd's comment: any replication software you're using is some kind of add-on thing, so that's what you should be asking about (the add-on, not Git).

Comment: Thanks for the input. To add more input this is the documentation I am following. https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.2/admin/enterprise-management/configuring-clustering/configuring-high-availability-replication-for-a-cluster